# Firebase storage - getting the contents of a file as a string

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

How can i get the contents of a file in firebase storage as a string in node js?

I am using a server which does not allow files to be saved, so downloading and then reading the file is not an option.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you have that doesn't work the way you expect.  Cloud Storage has a pretty well documented API, and you should try to make use of that on your own before posting a question.

Comment: What does the Firebase server have to do with your server? Those are two separate, unrelated servers.